# Creating user defined literals representing a data type

Tags: python, literals

There are literal that represent a built-in data type

### Examples

`""` represents a string

`{}` represents a dictionary

How can I make user-defined literals to represent a object of the type I want?

Comment: What is wrong with using the same symbols used in the class name followed by parenthesis? Can you give an example of exactly what you would like to use?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the behavior of operators on the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can’t do that in python

Or most other languages. You would have to change the python parser and the source code. So this is sadly not possible.